# Trailing command line argument in "psql -c" line: what is it?

Tags: postgresql, yaml, config, psql

I'm looking at a YAML config file for launching a cloud server.
I want to modify the file to use an RDS database instance rather than the PostgreSQL on the EC2 instance. I can't quite make sense of this trailing `aggregate"` at the end of the last three lines. I've done some googling around the `psql -c` command but can't seem to find an explanation or example of it used elsewhere. The reason it's a bit confusing is that the sample config uses the same string for database, user, password, and schema.

```
  - su postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE ROLE aggregate WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'aggregate'\""
  - su postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE aggregate WITH OWNER aggregate\""
  - su postgres -c "psql -c \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE aggregate TO aggregate\""
  - su postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE SCHEMA aggregate\" aggregate"
  - su postgres -c "psql -c \"ALTER SCHEMA aggregate OWNER TO aggregate\" aggregate"
  - su postgres -c "psql -c \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA aggregate TO aggregate\" aggregate"
```

Is the trailing `aggregate"` referring to the database inside which the schema being created/altered resides?

EDIT: The endpoint values are elsewhere in the config file, of course. The above commands are just what I need to run against the RDS database before launching the EC2 instance, and for the sake of clarity and security, I'd like to change the database, schema and username values, rather than just having everything be `aggregate`.

Comment: You'll have to show the exact error message.

Comment: "Trailing command line argument" does not look like an error generated by psql or PostgreSQL, so it is probably coming from somewhere else.  And YAML doesn't do anything.  What is reading the YAML and doing stuff with it?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the psql command is

```
psql [option…] [dbname [username]]
```

as defined in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-psql.html). This means that the trailing `aggregate` (note that the final `"` is part of the outer `su` command, not part of the `psql` command) is the DB name which you defined on the second line.